# Retrieve a non-const element from a const c++-vector

Tags: c++, vector, constants

in my program I have global data.

Every program module must have read and write access to the data. As of now, I do not use threading, but Qt's signals and slots and therefore - although I did not yet encounter crashes - I think I'll need synchronization somewhen.

Therefore, every module holds the data like this:

```
const std::vector<T>& data;
```

where T is a custom class. Therefore, every module can read the data. To keep it consistent, the `vector` itself is const to prohibit concurrent deletions or removals. Those are done using global functions (like `addToData(T elem)`, `removeFromData(int id)`) which can be synchronized. Note that the vector itself is declared to be shared by reference, such that changes in one of the global functions above will result in consistent data in every program module.

==> That means that data can be read and added/removed from everywhere in a safe way.

The problem I encountered is modification of the data. The setters of `T` are aware of the race-conditions. Using `data`, I want to allow calls like `data.at(3).setAttr("hello")`, but for constant vectors, at() just returns constant references. Why and how can I make it work? I can cast the constness away, but that feels wrong.

I am also open for suggestions considering my architecture.

Comment: I'd suggesting instead creating your own class that wraps up a `std::vector`, providing the synchronised access you need. (And not having global data)

Comment: If modifying is only synchronized with other modifications but not with reading, you have a data-race, which is UB. You want a reader-writer lock there, or some other safer idiom.

Comment: I guess you're asking how to get around the blurred lines between a `const` vector of elements and a vector of `const` elements; C++ doesn't make this easy, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by all the references to concurrent modifications and synchronisation when you don't use threading. Seems like all you need to protect against is recursive access to the vector (i.e. modifying the vector causes some function to be called which tries to modify the vector again). That's related but not exactly the same, and having global `addToData` / `removeFromData` functions doesn't necessarily help.

Comment: @BoBTFish The vector can already have synchronized access, I am asking about the elements of the vector (which can also be synchronized). I don't see how a vector-container could make the non-constant functions of the element accessible. :|

Comment: @Deduplicator That is not an issue: Reading information from T is only possible with functions (=> not directly), therefore I can synchronize those calls (for example with a reader-writer-lock, as you mentioned).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, that's _exactly_ the issue. Not good to hear that C++ makes that distinction hard. Have you ever had such issues with vector? If so, how did you solve those?

Comment: @JonathanWakely That is  an interesting issue, but fortunately I did not yet have to deal with that :)

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: Despite using `const` fervently, I actually haven't. I'm not sure how I've avoided it, frankly. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Too bad :( How do you deal with global data?

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: I don't have any global data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's cool. So how do you make sure your data is not global? Or, more localized: How do you deal with data that is needed literally everywhere and that must be kept in sync?

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: I don't follow. My designs do not allow that scenario to occur. Of course it may also simply be that I got lucky with project requirements ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you have links for me where I can read up on some designs you are using :) ?

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is exactly where you want to cast constness away.  You have carefully designed your system to work correctly so don't feel *badly* about casting away `const` when you're completely ready for it's and it the *right* thing to do.

Comment: It's still a kludge and it's still a hack and it's only acceptable because this is a bit of a flaw in C++. I'd still plaster comments all around that area of code explaining why you feel `const_cast` is acceptable and how you _know_ it's safe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Although I agree, the other answers will require an overhaul of my architecture. Therefore I will go with this answer for now and delay the overhaul :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Synchronizing writes leaving reads non-synchronized may/will corrupt memory too.
2. Casting constancy away smells.

Working low overhead solution (though not well encapsulated) is below. Idea is well summarized in a @JonathanWakely's comment: "add a global function that takes a functor and applies it to the non-const vector"

header.h

```
struct no_synchronization {
    struct mutex {}
    struct guard {
      guard(mutex&) {}
    };
};

struct serialized {
   typedef std::mutex mutex;
   typedef std::lock_guard<mutex> guard;
};

template <class T, class S = no_synchronization>
class spaghetti {
    typedef typename S::mutex mutex;
    typedef typename S::guard guard;

    static mutex mutex_;
    static std::vector<T> vector_;

    template <class F>
    static void read_global_vec(F const& f) {
        guard lock(mutex_);
        std::vector<T> const& ref = vector_;
        f(ref);
    }

    template <class F>
    static void write_global_vec(F const& f) {
        guard lock(mutex_);
        f(vector_);
    }
}
```

If the contents of the vector is changing infrequently then you can use copy-on-write with a shared_ptr to keep contention to the minimum.

Comment: @Jonathan "As of now"

Comment: @JonathanWakely - I updated the answer for general case. Note how easy it was to make synchronization pluggable.

Comment: It's quite a nice approach, but the question is "how do I get non-const access to elements of a const vector" and it may not be obvious to the OP that almost hidden in your answer is the suggestion "add a global function that takes a functor and applies it to the non-const vector"

Comment: @JonathanWakely Good point, that was in fact not clear at first glance! :)

Comment: @bobah Interesting approach... I think that might work! But I think my architecture needs some tweaking for that

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for suggestions

1. You can wrap `vector`, with a class that works mostly the same. This would also get rid of the global functions you mention, which is good. If you want the instance of your class to be `const`, use a `mutable` vector internally.
2. `const_cast`, but try to hide it somewhere in a function.
3. Store smart pointers. I hope I'm not wrong with this (it's been a while), but I think you can retrieve a non-const element through a const smart pointer.

To elaborate on (1) since I was asked to in the comment:

You need the functionality of vector, it's a pretty good match for your needs. But the interface of vector is clumsy for what you need. This is a situation which is often encountered, and a wrapper is the default solution. A wrapper is a new class, with an interface that matches your needs, but it's implementation is pretty much just delegating all the work to another class. The goal of using a wrapper is to make the wrapper object easier to use right and harder to use wrong. It might look somewhat like this (not tested, will not compile):

```
class AWrapperForDemonstration
{
public:
    MyCustomClass& GetByIndex(int i) const // can throw
    {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
         return _storage[i];
    }
    size_t Size(int i) const
    {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
         return _storage.size();
    }
    void Add(MyCustomClass& addThis)
    {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
         _storage.push_back(addThis);
    }
    bool Remove(MyCustomClass& removeThis)
    {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
         auto it =_storage.find(removeThis);
         if (it == _storage.end())
             return false;
         _storage.erase(it);
    }
    template <F> void ForEach(F const& f) const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        for (auto& i : _storage)
            f(i);
    }
private:
    std::vector<MyCustomClass> _storage;
    std::mutex _mutex;
}
```

Comment: Can you eleborate a bit on your first point? Would you create a class similar to the one of bobah?

Comment: @Max No, not at all. You have a concept/an idea of how your vector should be used. The class you use should implement that concept, and internally to that class use `vector` to do so. The code that uses your class shouldn't need to know that there is a `vector` inside. If you later decide the vector isn't a good choice, you can simply swap it with something more fitting to your needs, e.g. a `deque`.